# Can't access resources/ when deploying Spring Boot application to WebLogic

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, weblogic

When I run my application on the embedded tomcat server shipped with spring, I can access my static resources just fine. When I package the application as a WAR, and deploy it to WebLogic, it can't find the resources.

It is able to return the `index.html` via the controller, but actually accessing the resources directly by their mapping returns `404`. WebLogic also isn't recognizing the WEB-INF/weblogic.xml, as I'm not able to access the page by the `context-root` I've specified.

---

#### Directory Structure.

[image: Directory Structure]

---

#### `SpringLdapApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringLdapApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringLdapApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringLdapApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

#### `HomeController.java`

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

---

#### `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-ldap</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with LDAP</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>spring-dev-server</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>weblogic</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I think your directory structure is wrong. WEB-INF/weblogic.xml should be inside src/main/webapp directory as per maven standard directory layout

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. Please help.

Comment: @ahilash On the root of your other resources, the `@RequestMapping` needs to be a sub-route of "/". I used "/api".